# using google maps with swipe taps

Tags: android, google-maps, tabs, android-fragments, swipe

I try to start a tab, which can be swiped. It works fine! But if I try to implement Google Maps, then it works unit I switch the tab and go to the map back. I get these kind of Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(25324): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(25324): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment
```

I searched many times in google and couldn't find a solution.

This is the MainActivity class Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

GoogleMapOptions nMap;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
    // of the app.
    mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    // Specify that the Home/Up button should not be enabled, since there is no hierarchical
    // parent.
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

    // Specify that we will be displaying tabs in the action bar.
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener for when the
    // user swipes between sections.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // When swiping between different app sections, select the corresponding tab.
            // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the
            // Tab.
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
        // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
        // listener for when this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

public static class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                // The first section of the app is the most interesting -- it offers
                // a launchpad into the other demonstrations in this example application.

                Fragment f1 = new LayersDemoActivity2();


                return f1;

            default:
                // The other sections of the app are dummy placeholders.
                Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
                fragment.setArguments(args);
                return fragment;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch(position){
        case 0: return "Timeline";
        case 1: return "Chat";
        case 2: return "Fh";
        case 3: return "Mehr";
        default: return "Section " + (position + 1);
        }
       }
      }


/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_section_dummy, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(
                getString(R.string.dummy_section_text, args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
   }
}
```

Tab 1 calls this Fragment

```
public class LayersDemoActivity2 extends Fragment implements OnItemSelectedListener {


private GoogleMap mMap;

private CheckBox mTrafficCheckbox;
private CheckBox mMyLocationCheckbox;

//neu hinzugekommen
private LocationClient locationclient;
private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
//neu hinzugekommen

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layers_demo, container, false);


    // Demonstration of a collection-browsing activity.
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.traffic)
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    updateTraffic();
                }
            });

    // Demonstration of a collection-browsing activity.
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_location)
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    updateMyLocation();
                }
            });

    // Demonstration of a collection-browsing activity.
    rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1)
            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if (!checkReady()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    try{
                        LatLng hier = new LatLng(mMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(), mMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude());
                        Marker setzen = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(hier).title("Here I am!"));         
                    }catch(Exception e){

                    }                       


                }
            });        

    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.layers_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            getView().getContext(), R.array.layers_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    mTrafficCheckbox = (CheckBox) getView().findViewById(R.id.traffic);
    mMyLocationCheckbox = (CheckBox) getView().findViewById(R.id.my_location);


    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    if (mMap != null) {
        updateTraffic();
        updateMyLocation();
    }
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
    }
}

private boolean checkReady() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        //getView().Toast.makeText(this, R.string.map_not_ready, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}



private void updateTraffic() {
    if (!checkReady()) {
        return;
    }
    mMap.setTrafficEnabled(mTrafficCheckbox.isChecked());
}



private void updateMyLocation() {
    if (!checkReady()) {
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(mMyLocationCheckbox.isChecked());
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    setLayer((String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
}

private void setLayer(String layerName) {
    if (!checkReady()) {
        return;
    }
    if (layerName.equals(getString(R.string.normal))) {
        mMap.setMapType(MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    } else if (layerName.equals(getString(R.string.hybrid))) {
        mMap.setMapType(MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    } else if (layerName.equals(getString(R.string.satellite))) {
        mMap.setMapType(MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    } else if (layerName.equals(getString(R.string.terrain))) {
        mMap.setMapType(MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    } else {
        Log.i("LDA", "Error setting layer with name " + layerName);
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Do nothing.
    }

}
```

last but not least, this is layers_demo.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
<!-- A set of test checkboxes. -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/map"
    android:background="#D000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dp" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/layers_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/traffic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onTrafficToggled"
        android:text="@string/traffic" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/my_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onMyLocationToggled"
        android:text="@string/my_location" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:onClick="tagOnMyLocation"
    android:text="@string/tag_me" />
```

and the activity_main.xml layout

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I guess it has something to do with fragment, but I dont know how and I dont know why. Please help. :(

Comment: When you slide the viewpager do you have black background behide or overlapping the map ?

Comment: not really, it is like. Tab 1 with Map works fine, go to Tab 2, Works also fine. Tab 3 and 4 the same. But If I go back to Tab 1 with the map, a lot of Errors in LogCat. I can't see the map, the app will crash.

Comment: Try to change the mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(your number of pages + 1);

Answer (score 1):

Just paste this method after oncreatview method

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {

    Fragment f = (Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (f != null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
    }

    super.onDestroyView();
}
```